# Ending last chapter in latex before glossary/ index of acronymes

Tags: latex

I have the problem of the glossary/ index of acronymes still being in the last chapter of my latex document. This causes the chapter number to appear in the header of these pages. How can I close the last chapter before calling `\printglossary` such that glossary and acronyme list are not part of a chapter.
Relevant packages that I am using:

```
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
```

I already tried

```
\clearpage
\markboth{}{}
```

right before calling `\printglossary` but that does not seem to do the trick or even anything at all.

Edit:
The commands that I am using to create the pdf are the following (in this order):

```
latexmk
pdflatex document.tex
makeglossaries document
pdflatex document.tex
pdflatex document.tex
```

This is a (mostly minimal) example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
twoside, 
12pt,
numbers=noendperiod, 
ngerman,
openany, 
fleqn]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}
\ohead{\pagename~\pagemark}
\rehead{\chaptername~\thechapter}
\lohead{\headmark}                                                
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\small\rmfamily}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{glossary1}
{
    name=Glossary Entry 1,
    description={First Glossary Entry}
}
\newacronym{via}{VIA}{Very Important Acronyme}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    SOME TEXT
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \cleardoublepage
    \rehead{\chaptername~\thechapter}
    \lohead{\headmark}
    \rmfamily
    \chapter{ONE} Chapter 1 which uses \gls{glossary1}.
    \chapter{TWO} Chapter 2 is using a \gls{via}.
    \chapter{THREE} Chapter 3 just exists.
    \clearpage
    \printglossary[title={Glossar}]
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Akronyme}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Glossary is in the chapter (german: Kapitel) 3.]

As can be seen in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0OBX.png), the glossary (and also the following acronyme index) is inside chapter 3 (german: Kapitel 3, upper right corner). I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: I edited my post to include a minimal example and a screenshot showing the glossary to be part of chapter 3 (which I don't want to happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reset the header with `\rehead{}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
twoside, 
12pt,
numbers=noendperiod, 
ngerman,
openany, 
fleqn]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}
\ohead{\pagename~\pagemark}
\rehead{\chaptername~\thechapter}
\lohead{\headmark}                                                
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\small\rmfamily}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{glossary1}
{
    name=Glossary Entry 1,
    description={First Glossary Entry}
}
\newacronym{via}{VIA}{Very Important Acronyme}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    SOME TEXT
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \cleardoublepage
    \rehead{\chaptername~\thechapter}
    \lohead{\headmark}
    \rmfamily
    \chapter{ONE} Chapter 1 which uses \gls{glossary1}.
    \chapter{TWO} Chapter 2 is using a \gls{via}.
    \chapter{THREE} Chapter 3 just exists.
    \clearpage
    \rehead{}
    \lohead{}
    \printglossary[title={Glossar}]
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Akronyme}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\rehead{}` in combination with `\lohead{}` work exactly as needed, thanks! Now that I knew what to search for I read a little about these commands: When `doubleside` is set for `scrbook`, both of these commands need to be set (for odd `\lOhead{}` and even `\rEhead{}` pages). For one-sided docs only the odd-command is needed, as all pages are treated as being odd in that case.

I guess you know all of this, but just to clarify it for future readers.